# Randomly select download location when clicking URL

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How our site is setup now is we would like to have a way that a user clicks a button per say, and it automatically selects a random download location that is listed in the code.

For example, user clicks "Download!". It randomly selects a URL to visit in the code that is set for example:

"website.com/blah.zip"
OR
"website2.com/blah.zip"

Is this possible to do? We are trying to ease the bandwidth on our servers by having two download locations, and have the site randomly choose one.

Comment: How about `rand()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, an easy way to do it would be:

```
$array = array("website.com/blah.zip", "website2.com/blah.zip");
$val = array_rand($array);
echo $array[$val];
```

You can use as many different sites as you want, and it will give you a random site from that array.

EDIT: Solution to the question posed in the comments:

Have you array set up at the top of your file as before:

```
$array = array("website.com/blah.zip", "website2.com/blah.zip");
```

Then with each link you'd just need to do:

```
<a href="<?php echo $array[array_rand($array)]; ?>">Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example! We have a simple HTML link setup like so:

<li><a href="http://website.com/blahzip">Download Blah</a></li>

Do you know how we would we go about integrating this?

Comment: See my edit. It's essentially the same setup with a different `echo`.

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and adding the PHP tag back in? This answer doesn't really go with the question without it.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged `php (server-side)`, this is a part of `Javascript (client-side)`

When inserting the `Download` button, randomly select a `index value` from an array of links :

```
var arr = ["website.com/blah.zip", "website2.com/blah.zip"];
var len = arr.length;
var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * len) + 1);
```

Now change download source to `arr[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could store two URls in an array and pick one like bellow.

```
$rand_key = array_rand($url_options, 1);
echo $url_options[$rand_key];
```